# How can I stop the input when I enter end

Tags: c

got this little problem, I made this code for my task, it should input strings and print it in revese, the loop should end when you enter end, but it doesnt end, I know this is not how you check strings but I don't know how to correct it. Thanks in advance for help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void reverse(char str[]){

    int length;
    for(length=strlen(str)-1; length >= 0; length--){
        printf("%c",str[length]);
    }
}

int main(void){

    char str[]="";

    while(str != "end"){

        printf("\nEnter string: ");
        scanf("%s", str);
        reverse(str);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The *first* problem is this: `char str[]="";` That defines an array of only *one* character, and initializes it to the string terminator character `'\0'`. And arrays in C have a *fixed* size, you can't create dynamic arrays.

Comment: The *second* problem is the comparison `str != "end"`, which will compare two *pointers*. Two pointers that will *never* be equal. All in all, it seem you have skipped some rather important chapters in your beginners books. Or you need to invest in some books.

Comment: Instead of "enter string", consider printing "enter one word", or something, because %s reads that, one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have many problems in your code :

1. when you write `char str[]="";` this is will create a string of `size = 1` only which will not accept any string you enter except for only one `char` , so you should do `char str[50];` where **50** is the max expected length of the entered string.
2. it's not `while(str != "end")` it's , `while(strcmp(str,"end") != 0)` as you want to compare the strings itself not addresses
3. it's better to write `scanf("%49s", str);` than `scanf("%s", str);` just to make sure that the entered string will always fit in your array
4. in this line `length = strlen(str)-1;` , the `strlen` function return `unsigned long long` , so you should typecast that and write `length = (int)strlen(str)-1;` instead

with this all being said , this is the edited code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char str[]){

    int length;
    for(length = (int)strlen(str)-1; length >= 0; length--){
        printf("%c",str[length]);
    }
}

int main(void){

    char str[50];

    while(strcmp(str,"end") != 0){

        printf("\nEnter string: ");
        scanf("%49s", str);
        reverse(str);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
Enter string:abcd
 dcba
Enter string:end
 dne
Process finished with exit code 0
```